# Properly eliminating duplicates from overlapping strings in R?

Tags: regex, r, edit

I'd like to ask a follow-up question to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009761/proper-use-of-gsub-regular-expressions-in-r), please, because an additional problem arose: I discovered subjects (Cultural Studies, e.g.) which belong to more than one category (Arts & Humanities and Social Sciences), i.e. there is overlap which has to be considered.

I have long lists of categories such as this machine readable example:

```
AB <- c("Science","Arts & Humanities","Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences","Science","Arts & Humanities; Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences","Science","Science; Social Sciences","Social Sciences; Science")
```

So it looks like this:

```
> AB  
[1] "Science"                                               "Arts & Humanities"  
[3] "Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences"                    "Science"  
[5] "Arts & Humanities; Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences" "Science"  
[7] "Science; Social Sciences"                              "Social Sciences; Science"
```

I would like to edit these terms and eliminate duplicates in order to get this result:

```
[1] "Science"                                    "Arts & Humanities"  
[3] "Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences"         "Science"  
[5] "Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences"         "Science"  
[7] "Science; Social Sciences"                   "Science; Social Sciences"
```

So I'm looking for another loop to eliminate the duplicate in #5. I tried using *strsplit()* and *unique()* but this didn't work:

```
> unique(strsplit(AB, "; *"))  
[[1]]  
[1] "Science"  

[[2]]  
[1] "Arts & Humanities"  

[[3]]  
[1] "Arts & Humanities" "Social Sciences"  

[[4]]  
[1] "Arts & Humanities" "Arts & Humanities" "Social Sciences"  

[[5]]  
[1] "Social Sciences" "Science"
```

So I would like to ask you again, please: How can I achieve the correct output mentioned above?
Thank you very much in advance for your consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with a trailing or leading white space.  If you apply this to AB it will take care of this for you:

```
fun <- function(text.var){
    x <- unlist(strsplit(text.var, ";"))
    Trim <- function(x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
    paste(sort(unique(Trim(x))), collapse="; ")
}

sapply(AB, fun, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Yielding:

```
> sapply(AB, fun, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
[1] "Science"                            "Arts & Humanities"                 
[3] "Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences" "Science"                           
[5] "Arts & Humanities; Social Sciences" "Science"                           
[7] "Science; Social Sciences"           "Science; Social Sciences"
```

Comment: There's also `trim()` in the gdata package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @Tyler Rinker ! Unfortunately this gives me **Error in unique(Trim(x)) : couldn't find function "Trim"** Do I have to install the gdata package first?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I didn't define it as a function.  Try it now.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me, @Tyler Rinker ! I do appreciate it! It works very well now! May I ask you something else, please? What do I have to add to the function so that the same terms ("Science; Social Sciences" and "Social Sciences; Science", e.g.) will be understood as equal and summed up in one category despite their different word order? I edited the seventh record in my example above to reflect this.

Comment: @user1496104 Good question.  May I ask that you start a new question though and perhaps link to this one.  That keeps this thread much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your encouragement, @Tyler Rinker ! No worries, I've got it myself now and edited your solution to reflect it.

Comment: I actually worked it through and have a pretty cool `agrep` solution with my beta package `qdap` if you want to post.